# How to move Workbooks from one folder to another with conditions?

Tags: vba, excel

There is a ready script that counts number of rows in Workbooks from a selected folder. In case number of rows in any workbook is more than 1, this workbook is copied and saved into another folder.

```
    Sub OpenFiles()
    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim TargetWB As Workbook

    MyFolder = GetFolder("C:\Users\user\Desktop") 
    MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "*.*")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Do While MyFile <> ""
        Set TargetWB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile & "*.*")
        With TargetWB
            If CountUsedRows(TargetWB) > 1 Then
                .SaveAs "C:\Users\user\Desktop\vba\" & MyFile
            End If
            .Close
        End With
    MyFile = Dir
    Loop

    'Workbooks.Close savechanges:=False

   Shell "explorer.exe C:\Users\user\Desktop\vba", vbMaximizedFocus 
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    End Sub


Function GetFolder(strPath As String) As String
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = strPath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function

Function CountUsedRows(Wbk As Workbook) As Long
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Set WS = Wbk.Sheets(1)
    CountUsedRows = WS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 
End Function
```

Is it possible to `move` a Worbook to another folder insted of coping it in case it contains more than 1 row.

And is it possible to use something like:  `Workbooks.Close savechanges:=False` in order to close chosen Workbooks after rows counting? Thanks!

Comment: 1) as I see you alredy close each workbook after counting rows: `.Close`. 2) you could use `SaveAs` (you already have it) to save in another folder and than `Kill "oldPath"` to remove file from previous folder

Comment: actually all the workbooks remain opened, its not a problem if i have just 3 workbooks, but with 10 or 20 it becomes problematic. And i should also close a source folder from where i take workbooks for row count

Comment: try to use `.Close SaveChanges:=False`

Comment: i've put .Close SaveChanges:=False insted of .Close, but files remains still open and the folder from which i choose files too

Answer (score 0):

You can move a file easily using the `MoveFile` method of `FileSystemObject` object. To use this type with early binding add a reference to Microsoft Sripting Runtime in your VBA project.